How to author data for spawning enemies in waves?
I'm ready to start working on a prototype of a 2D game. My game has a few phases it cycles through, two of them being a gathering/crafting phase, then a defending phase. In the defending phase, you have to fight off waves of enemies attacking the player outside of their home.
I have an array where I have the number of days that it has been, and the game ends on day 50. I was planning on hardcoding what enemies spawn each day so I have full control of each 'level.' I was thinking of storing either a giant array or list where I plan out the flow of combat.
I'm imagining it might look something like this, as a very rough estimate. I'm looking for help on how I might write out the ideas that I have outlined below programmatically.
I've included how I believe the logic might work. I'd like to ask about how to translate it into proper code, if what I've written is possible to do as written and doesn't require changing anything around. I'm specifically unsure of setting wait for seconds inside the enemy list, or how to go about setting day equal to the day in DaysSurvived.
int[] DaysSurvived = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
        16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,
        36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50};

public List <EnemiesToSpawn> enemyWaves = new List <EnemyWave>
{
// Example for the first day
//new EnemyWave { //Set day = 1 here, create the list of enemies for the first day, 
//example: enemiesToSpawn = new List<Enemies>{ solider1, solider2, set wait for seconds(60),
//then spawn 2 more soliders}
//Go on to define the rest of the days here
//set day equal to its counterpart in DaysSurvived,
//and use that to call up the list of what enemies to spawn that day
}


Yes, it could. But take your DaysSurvived array, it has actually no useful information. If you are just interested in the days survived, a simple integer is enough that you increase each day/ end of round. There are a lot of different ways on how you could spawn/ store which/ when each enemy per day should spawn, it will depend a lot on how easy you want to edit it, where to edit and by whom.

Generally I advise against asking "could this work?". Trying it and finding out where it serves your purposes well vs where you experience friction will always be far more informative than opinions from randos on the Internet like us.  You're probably asking because you feel some trepidation about the idea — something you're worried might break, or could be "better" on some particular axis. Can you edit your question and try to clarify that concern? The clearer the issue, the better we can target answers to help you.

This looks like a job for a custom data structure, or a few.
We'll define our own (non-MonoBehaviour) types to store structured data about each wave, and mark them as [System.Serializable] so that the compiler generates the glue that lets us see and edit this data in the Unity Inspector.
[System.Serializable]
public class EnemyGroup {
    public Enemy enemy;
    public int count = 1;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class EncounterWave {
    public int day;
    public float secondsBeforeSpawn;
    public List<EnemyGroup> enemies;
}

Then our day / wave / spawn manager class can include a list of these waves:
public List<EncounterWave> waves;

Which will show up for us to edit in the Inspector like so:

Then you can spawn the day's encounters like so:
public IEnumerator SpawnWaves(int daysSurvived) {
    var today = daysSurvived + 1;

    // Walk through the list of all waves.
    foreach (var wave in waves) {
        if (wave.day != today) continue; // Skip waves for other days.

        // If the wave specifies a delay, wait that long before spawning.
        if (wave.secondsBeforeSpawn > 0f)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(wave.secondsBeforeSpawn);

        // Proceed to spawn all enemy groups in this wave.
        foreach (var group in wave.enemies) {
            // You may have some logic for where to place each enemy in a wave.
            // Since I don't know your game rules for that, I'll elide that here.
            for (int i = 0; i < group.count; i++)
                Instantiate(group.enemy, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
        }

        // Continue on to the next wave. If there should be a delay
        // before that wave starts, specify that in the next wave's
        // secondsBeforeSpawn field.
    }
}

When your game progresses to a new day, you can initiate the day's waves by calling:
StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves(daysSurvived));

This will spawn enemies in waves for the specified day, in the order they appear in the list in the Inspector, with the delays you've configured between them. On days with nothing to spawn, it will quickly scan through the whole list and return immediately.
Note that this does not assume that you have only one wave of enemies per day, nor that the days are in chronological order. You can save a few iterations if that's true, but for a list that has only a few dozen entries and only gets traversed once per in-game day, this won't be a meaningful performance overhead.
You can of course add additional fields to these custom data types, like different locations/directions where each wave or group should approach from, sounds or visuals to announce the start of the wave, game modifiers to apply, etc. Or you can go to town with custom gizmos and property drawers like Oskar Stålberg's work authoring Viking raids for Bad North.
If you're concerned about how bulky that looks in the Inspector by default, a couple dozen lines of PropertyDrawer / OnValidate code can customize it into something much friendlier, while preserving the same underlying data structure:

That's probably a topic for a fresh thread though. Make sure you have the data structure you need to get the gameplay you want first, then you can post a new question to get help styling the editing interface for it to suit your workflow, if desired.
